# Show f is continuous if and only if for any x $\in$ X and any open set O$^y$ in Y containing f(x), ...

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces with topology $T^x$  and $T^y$

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function.

Show $f$ is continuous if and only if for any $x \in X$ and any open set $O^y$ in $Y$ containing $f(x)$, there is an open set $O^x$ in $X$ containing $x$, such that $f(O^x) \subseteq O^y$

I know that $f$ is continuous if and only if for every closed set $C$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$.

Also $f$ is continuous if and only if every open set O in Y, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$.

Let $x \in X$and suppose $f(x) \in O^y$ for some $O^y \in T^y$. Also there exists 
an open set $O^x$ in $X$ containing $x$, such that $f(O^x) \subseteq O^y$.

$\Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(O^y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hints:* $x \in f^{-1}(O^y)$ and
$$f(O^x) \subseteq O^y \Longrightarrow x \in O^x \subseteq f^{-1}(O^y).$$

> 1) Suppose that $f$ is continuous. If $x \in X$ and $O^y \ni f(x)$, then put $O^x := f^{-1}(O^y)$.
>  2) Now assume that for any $x \in X$ and $O^y \ni f(x)$ there is $O^x \ni x$ such that $f(O^x) \subseteq O^y$. Let's fix some open $O^y$ and prove that $f^{-1}(O^y)$ is open. If $x \in f^{-1}(O^y)$, then there is $O^x \ni x$ such that $f(O^x) \subseteq O^y$, i.e. $x \in O^x \subseteq f^{-1}(O^y)$. Since every point of $f^{-1}(O^y)$ has some open neighborhood also belonging to that set, $f^{-1}(O^y)$ is open.

Comment: Which direction of the iff is the hints for?

Comment: The first one for "only if", the second one for "if".

Comment: Could you explain more about your hints? I'm still stuck.

Comment: I added full solution as a spoiler.